# How to set up gitlab CI runners?

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci

I am asking the question here, because [documentation](https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlab-ci-runner#setup-runners) didn't help me.

During runner's setup, 2 things are being asked: url of gitlab CI coordinator and registration token. I don't get what any of them should be.

As for url, it could be either url of gitlab CI web interface (ex: `http://localhost:80/`) ot url related to build, which is described in build's advanced properties.

Registration token could be something from documentation - but the link to it is dead (see:  http://gitlab-ci-domain.com/admin/runners) or registration token from build's advanced properties.

However, when i try to supply to runner's setup url and registration token from build properties, i get access error which informs me that registration failed. Due to lack of understanding what those parameters should be, i cannot determine what is wrong.

Comment: Hi, I have exactly the same question, and it seems no one will answer ... have you figured it out ?

Comment: The answer i came to was: you can only setup runners for repositories where you have admin privileges. I do not think that makes sense, but - if we want to change that, we probably should change it ourselves

Answer (score 6, accepted):

the Url is your Gitci Url.
the token you mention its in your gitlabci under "runners" next to the line:

"To register new runner you should the following registration token. With this token the runner will request a unique runner token and use that for future communication"

Comment: In Gitlab CI "runners" only appear when user has administrative priviledges on gitlab server. I do not understand why this is set up that way.

Comment: sorry forgot to mention that =( i normally enter all the time as root but glad you figure it out =)

Comment: @Srv19 nowadays runners appears also in the project so you don't need administrative privileges

Comment: @ReDetection Nice. It really shouldn't have been an administrative task.

Answer (score 4):

If you can access the settings for a project, then you can find the information in Project Settings > Runners. There should be a box under Specific Runners that has the URL and token.

**EDIT:** As of GitLab 9.0, this info can be found under Settings > CI//CD Pipelines (per [Josh Noe](https://stackoverflow.com/users/732673/josh-noe))

**EDIT:** New location as of GitLab 9.3 (maybe earlier): Settings > Pipelines

**EDIT:** New location as of GitLab 10: Settings > CI / CD > Runners Settings

Comment: It's now in Settings -> CI//CD Pipelines.

Answer (score 2):

As of **GitLab Enterprise Edition 12.0.0-pre 8104b83f087**

The token can be found by:

1. Go to your gitlab project
2. Click on Settings
3. Click on CI/CD
4. Click on "Expand" on the Runners section
5. The token is under "Set up a specific Runner manually"

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Apparently the only way to do that is to be admin of Gitlab your CI server deals with yourself.

I find that unreasonable, but what could be done?..

Comment: That is only true for Instance Runners that can be used by all groups and projects on your GitLab instance. If you create Project-specific runners, users with Maintainer or higher roles on each project can view and add such runners, as described in https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/permissions.html